# Why is BRCA-1 mutation a dominant mutation?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, molecular-genetics, cancer

BRCA-1 gene is a tumor suppressor gene and undergoes a loss of function mutation to become cancer inducing. Why is it that only one allele needs to be mutated because loss of function mutations are usually recessive and requires the mutation of both alleles.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on when and where you are identifying the phenotype. [www.cancer.gov](http://www.cancer.gov) has much useful info, including a fact sheet:
https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/genetics/brca-fact-sheet

From that:

> Even if someone has inherited a harmful variant in BRCA1 or BRCA2 from
> one parent, they would have inherited a normal copy of that gene from
> the other parent ... But the normal copy can be lost or change in some
> cells in the body during that person’s lifetime. Such a change is
> called a somatic alteration. Cells that don’t have any functioning
> BRCA1 or BRCA2 proteins can grow out of control and become cancer.

The pre-existing loss of one functional allele from conception makes any later somatic inactivation of the other allele a homozygous loss of function rather than just a heterozygous LOF.